# Adding attributes to multiple textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

My ASP.Net webform contains a number of textboxes. I want to add "onfocus" and "onmouseover" attributes to ALL textboxes. I can do this using the following code:

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "javascript:this.select();");
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "javascript:this.select();");

TextBox2.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "javascript:this.select();");
TextBox2.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "javascript:this.select();");

TextBox3.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "javascript:this.select();");
TextBox3.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "javascript:this.select();");
```

But since the no. of TextBoxes are more then 35, I am thinking of using a loop to do so. I tried the following code:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    foreach  (Control ctl in Controls)
    {
        if (ctl is TextBox)
               ctl.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "javascript:this.select();");
    }
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

'System.Web.UI.Control' does not contain a definition for 'Attributes' and no extension method 'Attributes' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you forced to do this in the code behind? you can also do this via jquery...

Comment: @peroija, Can you elaborate or give me some examples. I am not very familiar with jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Linq's [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx). It returns all controls of a given type.

I suggest to add all of your `TextBoxes` into a container control, for example a `Panel` or `PlaceHolder`:

```
foreach(var txt in txtPanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    txt.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "javascript:this.select();");
    txt.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "javascript:this.select();");
}
```

Ensure that you've added `using System.Linq`.

Here's another similar approach which looks into all panels in the current page:

```
this.Form.Controls.OfType<Panel>()
                  .SelectMany(p => p.Controls.OfType<TextBox>());
foreach (TextBox txt in allTextBoxes){}
```

Note that you can also filter the `Panels` or `TextBoxes` with [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) (f.e. if the panels' id's start all with `txtPanel_`).

Comment: I had forgotten about casting. But those solutions didn't work even though there was no error during build. But the solution by "Tim Schmelter" is working. But since my TextBoxes were contained within multiple panels (7 in total), I am looking for alternate solutions.

Comment: @user77735: You can also use `Page.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()`, but then you might get textboxes that you don't want to include. I'll add another option...

Comment: @user77735: Edite my answer, use the `Form` property instead of the `Page`.

Answer (score 1):

The ctl object is just a webcontrol and although you're checking it's a TextBox, you're not casting it as one before using it...

Try...

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    foreach  (Control ctl in Controls)
    {
        if (ctl is TextBox)
               ((TextBox)ctl).Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "javascript:this.select();");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of ctl is still Control. In order for it to become a TextBox, you can cast it like this:

```
((TextBox)ctl).Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "javascript:this.select();");
```

or use the `as` operator:

```
(ctl as TextBox).Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "javascript:this.select();");
```

The difference between those two, is that `as` will return a `null` reference if the cast is not successfull, and the cast will throw an exception, but since you already check using the `is` operator, just use the one that looks better to you.
However, if you use multiple assignments, I would extract the cast to a variable, like:

```
if (ctl is TextBox)
{
  TextBox textBox = (TextBox) ctl;
  textBox.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "javascript:this.select();")
  .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast it to a TextBox. ctl is still a Control, which does not have the Attributes property.

```
((TextBox)ctl).Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "javascript:this.select();");
```