# ASP.net c# WebForms add an attribute to multiple textboxes on page_load

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I'm working on an old WebForms application that uses .Net Framework 2.0.  I would like to apply an attribute to all of the asp:textbox controls on page_load.  In newer versions of the framework (3.5 and newer) I can just use:

```
            foreach (var txt in panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            txt.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "capsLock(event);");
        }
```

But, since I can't use Linq, I need to find another way to get this done.  I found this previous post here ([Adding attributes to multiple textboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424230/adding-attributes-to-multiple-textboxes)), but the recommendations from there aren't adding the attribute to the textboxes as required.

I'm not opposed to using other options such as jQuery, but I'm not very experienced with it.

How can I add the onkeydown="capsLock(event)" to each asp:textbox on the aspx page on page_load?